# C# Скачивание изображения из документа по url на litres.ru (Режим только чтение)

Tags: c#, https, браузер

Здравствуйте! Недавно столкнулся с проблемой скачивания картинки с сайта litres.ru.

Есть некоторый url: .../pages/read_book_online/?file=15177364&page=0&rt=w640&ft=gif

---

Интерпретатор браузера воспринимает его как картинку и я хочу ее скачать, но возникла проблема, прямой ссылки на картинку (Gif) не существует. Т.е при попытке скачать картинку через HttpRequest (через Stream, HttpResponse и тп) или webclient.DownloadFile(url, "filename.gif") скачивается сама страница (ContentType = text/html). В браузере страница выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос: Как можно скачать картинку по типу "лкм -> save as image"?** 
Слышал про псевдобраузеры(поправьте если не так называю), которые грузят прямо api, симулируя работу настоящего браузера, и могут просчитывать все. Есть ли тогда что-то подобное в c#? Или есть другое решение? В общем случае мне нужно скачать уйму подобных страниц. Спасибо!

P.S Если не сложно, распишите поподробнее способ, думаю многим будет интересно:)

**UPD**: желательно без браузера из WindowsForms
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Запрос на получение картинки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Так есть ссылка на картинку или нет? Как скачать картинку, на которую нет ссылки? Что надо сделать то? Фиддлером ловили запрос на скачивание картинки браузером? Заголовки глядели запроса?

Comment: @tym32167 фото запроса на скачивание добавил, ссылки на картинку нет. Нужно симулировать браузерное "lkm -> сохранить картинку как"

Comment: А почему вам просто не дать ссылку на саму картинку? Погуглив, я нашел скорей всего от куда вы [качаете](https://pda.litres.ru/pages/read_book_online/?file=14266638&page=0&rt=w640&ft=jpg), взял первую ссылку из интернета, не `gif`, но все же ресурс походу тот. Далее я обычным `WebClient.DownloadFile` скачал без проблем данное изображение с этого сайта. Вопрос, в чем проблемы и как нам эту проблему воспроизвести?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да если погуглить, то и [готовый граббер](https://habrahabr.ru/post/334412/) найти можно

Comment: Там же пишут что у Литреса в мобильном приложении в трафике видны ссылки на PDF.

Comment: [Книжка эта стоит меньше 400 рублей.](https://www.litres.ru/boris-grigorevich-mirkin/vvedenie-v-analiz-dannyh-uchebnik-i-praktikum-12109572/) Как два раза пообедать в столовой какой. Или один кофе в кафе. Вы уверены что иначе никак нельзя?

Comment: @sanmai  книжка стоит не 400 рублей, а гораздо больше

Comment: @EvgeniyZ прошу привести пример, как вы через webclient не по прямой ссылке на файл, а ссылке на страницу, скачиваете Gif. 2) Мне нужно граббить на c#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решил проблему. Для получения Content-Type: image/gif, image/gif вместо text/html нужно ***ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО*** указать в ***Cookie SID*** (вот такая на litres.ru аунтификация:) ). Скачать книгу в Jpeg можно так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    var bytes = web.DownloadData(name.Replace("page=", $"page={i}"));

    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(bytes));
    img.Save($"{path}/page{i}.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Можете более подробно описать решение? С 1-м примером реализации (на примере одной страницы книги / картинки). Столкнулся с похожей проблемой, только у меня формат GIF (не суть).
Не понимаю как превратить ссылку вида: https://www.litres.ru/pages/get_pdf_page/?file=45081578&page=1&rt=w1900&ft=gif в gif-файл (или сохранить как gif-файл). Google Chrome её отрисовывает нормально, но менеджер загрузок например не видит. Я вижу по примеру выше что вы подменяете счетчик страниц в итоговой ссылке и сохраняете jpeg как page{n}, но какова итоговая ссылка? Какой она должна быть? >>>Для получения Content-

Comment: @A.Popov Дайте пример url, не помню, что там было, но мб смогу помочь

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста в эту тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/935819/213987 - её создал @A.Popov со своим вопросом.