# Скачать закрытый pdf на litres.ru

Tags: python

@Xambey 
Я новичок и не имею репутации оставлять комментарии в вопросе:
[724063](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/724063/c-%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-url-%D0%BD%D0%B0-litres-ru-%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/724255?noredirect=1#comment1553493_724255)

Пример url: https://www.litres.ru/pages/get_pdf_page/?file=45081578&page=1&rt=w1900&ft=gif

Можете более подробно описать решение? С примером реализации (на примере одной страницы книги / картинки).

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой, только у меня формат GIF (не суть). Не понимаю как превратить ссылку вида: https://www.litres.ru/pages/get_pdf_page/?file=45081578&page=1&rt=w1900&ft=gif в gif-файл (или сохранить как gif-файл).

Google Chrome её отрисовывает нормально, но менеджер загрузок например не видит.

Я вижу по примеру выше что вы подменяете счетчик страниц в итоговой ссылке и сохраняете jpeg как page{n}, но какова итоговая ссылка? Какой она должна быть?

Заграбить я уже смогу сам на Python.

Буду признателен за ответ!

Comment: @Xambey вопрос вам

Comment: Вызов пользователя через @ сработает только для тех, кто отписался в вопросе или ответе. Ждите, пока кто-нибудь ещё зайдёт в вашу тему - не обязательно ответит автор того же вопроса, на который вы сослались.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не является вопросом, но комментарием к вопросу другого участника.

Comment: @MarianD как мне в таком случае поступить? Оставить комментарий в основном вопросе я не могу. Вопрос со ссылкой задать (по вашему мнению) тоже не могу.

Comment: Не надо оставлять комментарий в том вопросе. Вы правильно сделали, что задали свой собственный вопрос, потому что у вас похожая, но не полностью идентичная задача. Всё что нужно - это привести ваш код, который есть, чётче обозначить проблему. Как я понимаю - у вас есть парсер сайта и вы хотите функцию, которая по url скачает файл на диск. Верно?

Comment: @AK спасибо. Да, но код тут не при чем. Я могу реализовать парсер и на C# и на Python и на чем угодно (хоть на vba). Вопрос именно в интерпретации (выдергивании) нужной ссылки. Т е как мне превратить (сорри, если это не совсем корректно сформулированный вопрос) ссылку https://www.litres.ru/pages/get_pdf_page/?file=45081578&page=1&rt=w1900&ft=gif в ссылку с gif? Именно с litres.ru
Автор основного вопроса решил эту проблему, но я не могу понять его ответ. А как это уже обернуть вокруг парсера - это детали)

Comment: Может быть кто-то из участников с репутацией больше 50 сможет оставить комментарий в основном вопросе за меня? Пример url: https://www.litres.ru/pages/get_pdf_page/?file=45081578&page=1&rt=w1900&ft=gif

Comment: Видимо, вам нужно иметь логин/пароль к сайту (он требует авторизации), получить текст страницы, распарсить, выцарапать нужные ссылки. Как парсить на c# например есть [общий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/420354/213987). Без логина-пароля никак не получить текст страницы.

Comment: @A.Popov - отредактируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы он *не являлся комментарием* (как вам уже посоветовал АК), и всё будет в порядке. Это не так сложно.

Comment: @A.Popov 1) на сколько я помню, я делал это будучи авторизованным. 2) глянул, что там сейчас на litres, те ссылки, что я видел, имеют уже другой формат. И в слое страницы присутствует прямая ссылка на картинку. Посмотрите внимательно на код ответа, весьма вероятно, что на странице есть ссылка либо для скачивания фрагмента либо целиковой гифки. @A K все верно написал. Если быть более точным, почитайте про то, как работает HTTP и в частности Cookies. Вам нужно сделать 1 запрос на авторизацию и из ответа set-cookie сохранить ключ, чтобы затем отправлять его с запросом на получение страницы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы скачать книгу постранично вам сначала нужно сделать запрос на авторизацию. Понять, что нужно отправлять можно при помощи web inspector в любом браузере (в google chrome - F12 / Network).

1. Просто смотрите, какой запрос делает браузер для получения cookies с ключем сессии. Парсите ключ из ответа.
2. Идете на страницу книги, будучи авторизованным. Открываете web inspector и находите в коде страницы (html) тег img или object или embed, смотря, что они используют для загрузки изображения или анимации. Находите ссылку на загрузку изображения/анимации.
3. Делаете запрос, как в пункте 2, скачивая все как поток. Ключевым моментом тут служит наличие cookie-токена для авторизации в headers. Если хотите все автоматизировать, то в в пункте 2 ищите ссылку на изображение/анимацию при помощи XPath или регулярных выражений, это не должно быть сложно 
   4) Преобразуете поток в файл. Об этом в интернете достаточно информации